# How to fix TypeError in Python when comparing values of two nodes of a Linked List

Tags: python-3.x, merge, linked-list

I am trying to compare the value of 2 nodes of 2 separate linked lists (the values will always be int), but it keeps throwing TypeError despite my best efforts to get around it.

Python version 3.7.4 on VS Code for Mac 1.37.0

This is code I wrote to merge two Linked Lists with values as int (which should be pre-sorted before being passed as arguments to the 'merge' method). The output needs to be a single sorted Linked List. I understand TypeError gets thrown if 2 values are being operated on while they are of incompatible type (e.g. str + int or int < object etc.).  To get around it, I tried forced type-casting, but that then creates AttributionError, since object at one point is 'None' and it doesn't get typecast to int.

```py
######## Definition of 'Node', 'LinkedList' #######
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
            return
        node = self.head
        while node.next is not None:
            node = node.next
        node.next = Node(value)

#### Where I need help #####
def merge(list1, list2):
    """
    Merge and sort two linked lists

    Args:
       list1, list2: two linked lists that need to be merged. They need to be pre-sorted before being passed as a argument.
    Returns:
       linked-list: Merged and sorted linked-list, a combination of list1 and list2
    """
    merged = LinkedList(None) # create an empty linked list
    if list1 is None:
        return list2
    if list2 is None:
        return list1

    list1_elt = list1.head  # start with heads of the two lists
    list2_elt = list2.head

    while list1_elt is not None or list2_elt is not None:
        # val1 = int(str(list1_elt.value))
        # val2 = int(str(list2_elt.value))
        # condition = val1 < val2
        # print("List1 value: {} and List2 value: {}".format(list1_elt.value, list2_elt.value))
        if list1_elt is None:
            # print("List2 value: {}".format(list2_elt.value))
            merged.append(list2_elt)
            list2_elt = list2_elt.next
        elif list2_elt is None:
            # print("List1 value: {}".format(list1_elt.value))
            merged.append(list1_elt)
            list1_elt = list1_elt.next
        elif list1_elt.value <= list2_elt.value:
        # elif val1 <= val2:
        # elif condition:
            # print("List1 value: {}".format(list1_elt.value))
            merged.append(list1_elt)
            list1_elt = list1_elt.next
        else:
            # print("List2 value: {}".format(list2_elt.value))
            merged.append(list2_elt)
            list2_elt = list2_elt.next
    return merged


##### TEST CODE TO CHECK #######

# First Test scenario
linked_list = LinkedList(Node(1))
linked_list.append(Node(3))
linked_list.append(Node(5))

second_linked_list = LinkedList(Node(2))
second_linked_list.append(4)

merged = merge(linked_list, second_linked_list)
node = merged.head
while node is not None:
    #This should print 1 2 3 4 5
    print(node.value)
    node = node.next
```

In the merge method definition, I keep getting an error at the part:

```py
        elif list1_elt.value <= list2_elt.value:
```

I've tried to store the values in two separate variables with forced typecasting, but I get other errors. I am at my wit's end to understand what I am doing wrong here. This is the error I get:

> File "filename.py", line 58, in merge
>      elif list1_elt.value <= list2_elt.value:
>   TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `value` with a Node rather than int, at

```
              self.head = Node(value)

              node.next = Node(value)
```

Either you can send int to `append` function as :

```
              linked_list.append(5)
```

or directly assign the Node

```
              self.head = value

              node.next = value
```

I would suggest the first method as you should send the value which you want to insert into the list and your `append` function is also expecting a value.